# Error al llamar a un procedimiento almacenado de sql server con node js

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, nodejs, mssql

estoy haciendo una web en node y al intentar llamar a un procedimiento almacenado que tengo creado en mi sql server, no logro mandarle el parámetro del usuario y me da un error, este es mi código de node:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    let body = req.body;
    let user = body.user;
    console.log(user);

    let login = async() => {
        await sql.connect(config);
        let db = new sql.Request();
        let usuarioDB = await db.execute(`login_CARNET`, {
            USER: user
        });
        return usuarioDB.recordset;
    }

    login().then(usuario => {
        console.log(usuario);
    }).catch(err => console.log('error al hacer el login', err));

});
```

y este mi procedimiento que esta en SQL Server Management

```
USE [PruebasHector]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[login_CARNET]    Script Date: 27/09/2020 12:27:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[login_CARNET]
@USER AS VARCHAR(200)
AS


SELECT * FROM tbl_usuarios_CARNET WHERE usuario = @USER
```

pero no soy capaz de pasarle el usuario, me da este error

```
RequestError: Procedure or function 'login_CARNET' expects parameter '@USER', which was not supplied.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que estas utilizando el paquete [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)

- [node-mssql > Microsoft SQL Server client for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)

Allí podrías ver que en la ayuda, que también esta en el repositorio en github la parte de [enviar parámetros con nombre con el método input](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#input-name-type-value)

```
request.input('input_parameter', value)
request.input('input_parameter', sql.Int, value)
```

En tu ejemplo seria enviar

```
db.input('user', sql.VarChar(50), user)
```

algo así completo...

```
 let db = new sql.Request();
 db.input('user', sql.VarChar(50), user)
 let usuarioDB = await db.execute('login_CARNET',(err, result) => {
    // ... error checks

   console.log(result.recordset[0].value) // return 
   console.log(result.rowsAffected) // Returns number of affected rows in case of INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement.

   ps.unprepare(err => {
    // ... error checks
   })
```

})

Enlaces que te pueden servir de ayuda

- [input (name, [type], value) > Add an input parameter to the request.](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#input-name-type-value)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perféctamente